# MySql shell command not replicated to slave - "LOAD DATA INFILE"

Tags: mysql, replication

I have a shell script that looks something like that:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 mysql -udb_user -pdb_password -e "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/srv/some_file.csv'
 INTO TABLE db_name.db_table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'  
(\`col1\`,\`col2\`,\`col3\`);"
```

the problem is that when I run this script on my master server the call doesnt get replicated to the slave server (even though `/srv/some_file.csv` exists on both servers).

any ideas how to make shell command replicate over servers?

Comment: i voted the other one as duplication, it had a problem with identifying me as the author....

Comment: @DTest BTW, following our disscussion from the other question, my version of mysql should support the `load data` and when i run it from the mysql shell it works and being replicated, but when i run from the linux shell it only works on the master and not on the slave

Comment: I am assuming when you run it through the -e flag, that it actually makes the changes on the master server?

Comment: yes, when using running with the -e flag the changes are made on the master but dont get replicated to the slave. if i the same query on a mysql shell, data is affected on the master and the slave